# В очереди проверок небольшие косяки локализации

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

В первом случае нет запятой.
Во втором - лишний пробел.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прям дубликат за дубликатом, тов. Suvitruf! :)